# Nginx + Multiple docker containers on same IP but different ports using SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

Having a headache trying to get Nginx to work as a proxy between a single IP but multiple ports, all pointing to different containers running on docker.

Currently I can see that the https requests are working, however, I can't figure out why it's not showing the correct screen which visualizer should show (it should show some random code using curl but instead shows a server error).

The default.conf file I'm using is this:

```
server {
listen 8080 ssl http2;
server_name viz.test.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my.key;

ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_intercept_errors on;

proxy_pass http://visualizer;
}

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

I did notice that I'm missing an upstream section that includes 'visualizer' but I'm unsure of the format that should take, I've tried using upstream but I don't know if it should include the server IP and port or what. Currently the server I'm running this on doesn't have a domain name, only an IP address.

Any help would be appreciated as Nginx is proving far more difficult to understand, and tutorials seem to be missing key pieces of information (such as getting SSL working correctly on multiple containers in docker).

Comment: "Currently the server I'm running this on doesn't have a domain name, only an IP address". So why do u have `server_name viz.test.com;` ?

Comment: that's just a local server address added to my hosts file for testing

Comment: I assume visualizer is the name of a docker container? Does it have an exposed port 80?

Comment: Check if all your service in visualizer are ok when you access directly. What type off error that you got from browser ? How do you config your upstream ?

Comment: I'm getting a 302 error. Visualizer works fine without https. The upstream is something like this, but I'm not 100% sure it's correct:

upstream visualizer {
        server visualizer:8080;
    }

Visualizer has an exposed port 8080

Comment: proxy_pass http://visualizer:8080; then. As default HTTP is 80.

Comment: I tried adding proxy_pass http://visualizer:8080 but I still get the same 302 error when I try running a curl on https://vis.test.com